# How can I remove the horizontal space after a single item in a description list?

Tags: spacing, lists, description

In a description list, I would like to keep the normal spacing after the item for one item, but eliminate it for others. The `enumitem` package lets you eliminate the space for all items:

```
\begin{description}[labelsep = 0ex]
           \item[Faint]  -- but \emph{faint} is more general, as is
           \item[Swoon].
         \end{description}
```

[image]

But I would like to have the typical spacing after "faint" but no space after "swoon".

Comment: Are there  other items after ‘Swoon’?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Leave the default spacing in place for the list and use `\hspace{-\labelsep}` for those items where you want it to disappear.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{description}%[labelsep = 0ex]
           \item[Faint]  -- but \emph{faint} is more general, as is
           \item[Swoon]\hspace{-\labelsep}.
\end{description}


\end{document}
```

[image]